# What is causing my python script using Google APIs to throw a status code 3 & 6?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, http-status-codes, google-photos-api

I'm attempting to download all image files from a specified Google doc, save the image files to a designated directory on my machine then upload all the image files to a designated Google photo album.

The error I'm running into is occurring when I batch the files for upload to Google Photos. In looking it up it seems to be an issue with duplicate files. I'm not seeing any duplicates in Google Photos and according to the Google Photos library API documentation, it should allow for duplicates regardless.

I've verified my tokens and creds are up-to-date and valid. I'm well under the quota limit of 30 requests a minute, the image files are well under the file size limit and are in a supported format. All other functions of the code are behaving as expected, including the creation of the photo album in google photos, its just empty.

Code

```
    import time
import random
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload, MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
import pickle
import os
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import base64


def create_album(photos_service, album_title):
    print(f"Start create_album with photo_service: {photos_service} album_title: {photos_service}")
    # List all albums
    albums_list = photos_service.albums().list().execute()
    print(f"albums_list: {albums_list}")

    # Check if album already exists
    for album in albums_list.get('albums', []):
        if album.get('title') == album_title:
            return album  # Return the existing album

    # If album does not exist, create a new one
    create_album_body = {
        'album': {'title': album_title}
    }
    return photos_service.albums().create(body=create_album_body).execute()

def upload_image(image_path):
    # Read the image file in binary mode
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as photo_file:
        binary_photo_data = photo_file.read()

    # Convert the binary data to base64
    base64_photo_data = base64.b64encode(binary_photo_data).decode('utf-8')

    # Create the headers for the upload request
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.token,
        'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'raw',
        'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': os.path.basename(image_path),
    }

    # Make the POST request to upload the image and get the upload token
    upload_response = requests.post(
        'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads',
        headers=headers,
        data=base64_photo_data
    )

    # Check if the upload was successful
    if upload_response.status_code == 200:
        upload_token = upload_response.text
        if upload_token:
            return upload_token
        else:
            print(f"Upload succeeded but no upload token received for image: {image_path}")
            return None
    else:
        print(f"Upload failed with status code: {upload_response.status_code} for image: {image_path}")
        return None
    

def batch_upload_images(photos_service, album_id, image_paths):
    new_media_items = []

    for i in range(0, len(image_paths), 30):
        batch = image_paths[i:i+30]
        for image_path in batch:
            # Upload the image and get the upload token
            upload_token = upload_image(image_path)
            if upload_token is None:
                print(f"Failed to upload image: {image_path}")
                continue
            
            print(f"Uploaded image successfully: {image_path}")
            # print(f"Upload token: {upload_token}")  # Print the upload token

            # Add the new media item to the list
            new_media_items.append({
                'description': 'My new photo',
                'simpleMediaItem': {'uploadToken': upload_token}
            })
            print(f"New media item: {new_media_items}")

        # Create the media items in a single batch request
        file_metadata = {
            'albumId': album_id,
            'newMediaItems': new_media_items
        }
        response = photos_service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=file_metadata).execute()
        print(f"Batch create response: {response}")  # Print the batch create response

        for result in response.get('newMediaItemResults', []):
            print(f"Media item status: {result.get('status', {}).get('message')}")

        if i + 30 < len(image_paths):
            time.sleep(60)  # Wait for 60 seconds if there are more images to upload



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg.theme('SandyBeach')
    ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Please enter the save path, the file_id, and the album name')],
        [sg.Text('Save Path', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('File ID', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Album Name', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
    event, values = window.read()
    window.close()

    save_path = values[0] if values[0] is not None else 'default_save_path'
    album_name = values[2]

    if not os.path.exists('Keeps/' + save_path):
        os.makedirs('Keeps/' + save_path)

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            if os.path.getsize('token.pickle') > 0:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
            else:
                creds = None

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    photos_service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=creds, static_discovery=False)

    file_id = values[1]
    request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/html')
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

    html_content = fh.getvalue().decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    new_album = create_album(photos_service, album_name)
    print(f"New album: {new_album}")
    album_id = new_album['id']

    image_counter = 1
    image_paths = []
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        img_url = img['src']
        img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
        img_name = "Image" + str(image_counter)
        image_counter += 1

        img_object = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
        img_path = os.path.join('Keeps/' + save_path + '/', img_name + '.' + img_object.format)
        print(f"Saving image: {img_path}")
        img_object.save(img_path)

        image_paths.append(img_path)

        # Batch upload the images every 50 images
        if len(image_paths) >= 50:
            batch_upload_images(photos_service, album_id, image_paths)
            image_paths = []
    
    if image_paths:
        batch_upload_images(photos_service, album_id, image_paths)
```

Logs

```
Batch create response: {'newMediaItemResults': [{'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 3, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}, {'uploadToken': 'token', 'status': {'code': 6, 'message': 'Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.'}}]}
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
Media item status: Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the google Photos API requires binary format for file uploads. You must covert the images to binary or else the creation cannot happen.

Comment: I think I'm already doing that with ```with open(image_path, 'rb') as photo_file:
    binary_photo_data = photo_file.read()``` and ```base64_photo_data = base64.b64encode(binary_photo_data).decode('utf-8')```